# How to fix "The display settings could not be saved" message with Oculus Rift

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I am running Windows 8.1 under Boot Camp on a MacBook Pro Retina 15" at its native resolution of 2880x1800, with an Oculus Rift DK2 connected as an extended display at its native resolution of 1920x1080, and the Oculus Runtime 0.6.0.0 installed and running.

The Windows Display panel has "Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays" checked, and the scaling set to 250%.

While testing some software I made the Rift the primary display, and now I want to go back to the MacBook as the main display and the Rift as the secondary display. But when I try to apply this change, I get this error: "The display settings could not be saved. Please try a different combination of display settings."

I've switched primary displays back and forth before without any problem, but for some reason it stopped working and I am stuck with the Rift as the primary display.

I tried switching the Rift to Direct Mode and back, and uninstalling and reinstalling the Oculus Runtime. I searched for the error message and found a number of discussions about triple monitors - not the problem here - and also one suggestion to delete a nonexistent registry key.

How can I get past this error message and force it to make the MBP the primary monitor again with the DK2 a secondary extended display?

Answer (score 1):

The trick, as suggested in [a comment on this page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a30a3bfd-c163-40f8-98ac-c85b7441797b/unable-to-save-display-settings-and-multiple-monitors), turned out to be to lower the resolution of both the MBP and the DK2. I set the MBP to 1920x1200 and the DK2 to 1600x900 and applied that change. Then I was able to set the MBP as the primary monitor and apply that successfully. After that I set both devices back to their native resolution again.

Interestingly enough, now the machine is back in the state it used to be in where I can freely switch the primary display back and forth between the MBP and DK2.